# Pre-populating a dropdown list cell based on a cell entry in the same row (Excel/VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, dropdown, rows

I am trying to force a "Yes/No" dropdown list (created by data validation from a list elsewhere in the workbook) to pre-populate with "No" when a certain cell on its same row is filled in.

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

On the 3rd data entry row, when I fill in the "ID" field with a value, I want the "Bought?" field for that row to pre-populate with "Yes" immediately, rather than having to go into the dropdown list itself and choose "Yes" or "No". This should leave the option for the field to be changed to "No" via the dropdown menu.

Is this something that can be done with standard excel data validation or do I need to use some VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if you ever got a satisfactory answer to this one, but if it were a VBA solution you were looking for, a Private Sub would achieve what you are after.  The following assumes the sheet in question is Sheet1, and the ID column is C.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range

If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 
Set c = Sheet1.Range(Target.Address)

    If c.Value <> "" Then
        c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Yes"
            Else
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in your column D.

`=IF(COUNTA(C2), "Yes","")` and copy down as required.

This formula will answer "Yes" when anything is entered in C2. Variations thereof would be `COUNT(C2)` if you want to respond to a number only or anything else to validate the entry, perhaps `COUNTA(A2:C2)=3`

I had a little problem entering the formula and found that the easiest way is to set the data validation only after the formula. But removing the check mark on *Ignore blanks* in the data validation itself also allowed me to complete the entry.

Of course, "Yes" is one of the entries permitted by the validation. Clicking the the drop-down's arrow and selecting an item from the list will remove the formula.